# Alter table dept drop constraint dno_notnull

Tags: oracle11g

here I am droping a `not null` constraint.  Is there any alternate statement for this in oracle?

```
SQL> alter table dept drop constraint dno_notnull;
```

Comment: fixed formatting and capitalization

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the constraint is actually a named "NOT NULL" constraint, rather than a check constraint defined as "check (dno is not null)":

```
alter table dept modify dno null;
```

A named not null constraint could for example be added at table creation time like this:

```
create table dept (dno integer constraint dno_notnull not null, ...);
```